# Switch target of UIGestureRecognizer mid-gesture?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a scrollview within `ViewControllerA`. When a user is at the end of the scrollview during a pan gesture, it automatically transitions to `ViewControllerB` which has it's own scrollview. This transition works fine. However, after transitioning to `ViewControllerB` the pan gesture from `ViewControllerA` no longer exists (because now we're in `ViewControllerB`). This requires the user to lift their finger and then start another pan gesture to move `ViewControllerB`'s scrollview.

What I want to happen is when a user is panning to the end of `ViewControllerA`'s scrollview, it continues scrolling `ViewControllerB`'s scrollview after the transition without the user lifting their finger if they are still in the middle of a pan gesture.

One issue I know of is that scrollviews have their own pan gesture recognizer that is not settable.

I have tried the following strategy with a delegate which doesn't currently work:

```
protocol MyPanGestureDelegate {
    func panInViewControllerB(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
}

class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
    // ViewControllerB is assigned to 'gestureDelegate' below
    var gestureDelegate: MyPanGestureDelegate!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panInViewControllerA(_:)))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

        gestureDelegate.panInViewControllerB(panGesture)
    }

}

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController, MyPanGestureDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate { 
    // 'myScrollView' is an IBOutlet for said scrollview
    func panInViewControllerB(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        myScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }
}

// I've also set 'shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer' to true
```

Is there a way to scroll a scrollview in one view controller, transition to another view controller, and continue scrolling a scrollview in another view controller all in one pan gesture?

Comment: Have you watched https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/235/? There might be a simpler approach.